# How to get data inside from JSON OBJECT

Tags: javascript, json

Note that this is an actual Javascript object, whereas
 JSON is a string that represents that object.

```
JSONExample = {
"frames": {
    "chaingun.png": {
        "frame": {
            "x": 1766,
            "y": 202,
            "w": 42,
            "h": 34
        },
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": true,
        "spriteSourceSize": {
            "x": 38,
            "y": 32,
            "w": 42,
            "h": 34
        },
        "sourceSize": {
            "w": 128,
            "h": 128
        }
    },
    "chaingun_impact.png": {
        "frame": {
            "x":1162,
            "y":322,
            "w":38,
            "h":34},
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": true,
        "spriteSourceSize": {
            "x":110,
            "y":111,
            "w":38,
            "h":34},
        "sourceSize": {
            "w":256,
            "h":256}
    },
    "chaingun_impact_0000.png": {
        "frame": {
            "x": 494,
            "y": 260,
            "w": 22,
            "h": 22
        },
        "rotated": false,
        "trimmed": true,
        "spriteSourceSize": {
            "x": 113,
            "y": 108,
            "w": 22,
            "h": 22
        },
        "sourceSize": {
            "w": 256,
            "h": 256
        }
    }
}
};
```

The above is an example of how the JSON would be structured.
 Note that chaingun_impact.png is not here, we'll call your
 parseJSON function with the full JSON input.

```
parseJSON = function (weaponJSON) {
 // Your Code here 

};
```

I want to  grab the 'x' data field within 'spriteSourceSize' of 'chaingun_impact.png' .

Thanks in advace

**Edit**

and this is what i tried but it doesn't work

```
var parsedjson =  JSON.parse(weaponJSON);
alert(parsedjson);
console.log(pardesjson);
var x = parsedjson ['frames']['chaingun_impact.png']['spriteSourceSize'][x];
console.log(x);
```

Comment: and what you have tried?

Comment: use `var parsedjson = JSON.parse(JSONExample);` you need to pass the JSONObject to the parse method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `parsedjson['frames']['chaingun_impact.png']['spriteSourceSize']['x'];`

The `'x'` also needs quotes.

You could also do it this way:

```
parsedjson.frames['chaingun_impact.png'].spriteSourceSize.x;
```

Comment: but in console it is saying that 'parsedjson is undefined'

Comment: @Smartboy is `weaponJSON` a string or already an object?  If it's the latter you don't need `JSON.parse`.

Comment: `weaponJSON` is a string which is sent as a paramter we need to parse it first into json obkect and then need to get value of `x`

Comment: Show me on jsfiddle.net please

Comment: but i need to ask one thing

Comment: Go ahead; I'm happy to help

Comment: why did u use `frames['chaingun_impact.png']` like this . we cannot also use like `frames.chaingun_impact.png` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24010/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-smartboy)